# Using Model function

Tags: laravel

I have `Category` Model like below

```
class Category extends Model
{    
    public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany(User::class)->where("active_status",1)->where("user_type", 'user');
    }
}
```

I have `User` Model like below

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function getFullName()
    {
        return $this->first_name.' '.$this->middle_name.' '.$this->last_name;
    }
}
```

My controller code is like below

```
$category = Category::join('users', 'users.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')->get();
```

I am trying to use below code in `view`

```
@foreach( $result as $spc )

  $spc->getFullName();

@endforeach
```

I am getting error like below

```
[2019-09-24 14:45:43] laravel.ERROR: Call to undefined method App\Category::getFullName()
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear... `$spc` is a `Category`, not a `User`, and you've defined the function on your `User` class. Also, `getFullName()` should be `getFullNameAttribute()`, and calling `$user->full_name` will magically return the full name. See accessors: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: Also you're not declaring any [relation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships)... If you follow the official guidelines will be much easier to retrieve the relation (`Category::with('users')->get()`) and show it in your view (`$spc->user->getFullName()`)

Comment: @IlGala Just a heads up, `$spc->user->getFullName()` would be an error; `$spc->user` should be `$spc->users`, and you'd need to loop that, `@foreach($spc->users AS $user) {{ $user->getFullName() }} @endforeach`

Comment: @TimLewis right... My mistake, didn't see it's a `HasMany` relation

Comment: @IlGala No worries :) I would definitely consider converting your comment to an answer; you've got the right approach and reasoning to solve this.

Comment: I'm answering also to another question so... I'll answer to this in a few! :)

Comment: @IlGala, I made a comment in your Answer. Please reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Following the comments, the best way to achieve your goal is to use properly the [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships)

So in your controller change your query from

```php
$category = Category::join('users', 'users.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')->get();
```

to

```php
$categories = Category::with('users')->get();
```

Now the result will be a collection of `Category` with the `users` relation eagerly loaded, something like:

```
[
  {"id": 1, "name": "My category 1", "users": [{"id": 1, "mail": "user1@example.com"}, {"id": 2, "mail": "user2@example.com"}]},
  {"id": 2, "name": "My category 2", "users": []},
  {"id": 3, "name": "My category 3", "users": [{"id": 7, "mail": "user7@example.com"}]},
]
```

in your view with a simple `foreach` you can iterate the categories and each user:

```php
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Users</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($categories as $category)
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ $category->id }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ $category->name }}
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    @foreach($category->users as $user)
                    <li>
                        {{ $user->getFullName()}}
                    </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Side note

I saw that your relation is declared as

```php
public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany(User::class)->where("active_status",1)->where("user_type", 'user');
}
```

I don't like very much to add all those `where` inside the relation declaration. I think it's a better approach using the [local scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#local-scopes) since that code may be used in other parts of your code.

Comment: Thanks @IIGala for you nice Answer. It is working. But I need to get `{{ $category->name }}` inside the loop (`@foreach($category->users as $user)`). How can I do that ? I have to print `category_name` with each `user` individually. Thanks.

Comment: @abuabu It's a nested loop, you have access to `$category` in that second foreach, so simply `{{ $category->name }}`

Comment: Thanks @TimLewis. But I am using like this. `$result = array();
                        foreach($category as $cat) {
                            foreach($cat->users()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20) as $value) {
                                $result[] = $value;
                            }
                        }foreach( $result as $spc ){ // some code here, I would like to get category_name here  }`

Comment: Why are you nesting so many foreach? It's a nonsense...  anyway IMHO you should change the initialization of the result array... something like `$result[] = ['category' => $cat->name, 'users' => $value];` and in the last loop you have both the attributes